# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in exe

Tags: c#

while using a sql query with function

```
private void DisplayAll(string sql)
        {
            SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(cString);
            connection.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataadapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();

        }
```

information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
how to solve this

Comment: My guess is that whatever assembly you've referenced for the SQLite stuff up there is outdated and incompatible with .NET 4. Use a newer version of the assembly if available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use this startup tag in your `app.config` under `configuration` node

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: great....@user3300714 plz mark it as answer so that it will be helpful for others